# List Picker selected value and listbox selected value in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listbox

How do I get the listbox selected value and listpicker selected value in OnNavigated method,
I have list picker and listbox binded with items that come from web service response, I know how to get listbox and list picker selected value in selection changed event, but how do I get those values in other events?
Thanks!!

```
void client_live_permissionCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.live_permissionCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      LIST data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as LIST;
        long id = data.Id;
        string name = data.Name;
    }
```

but I debug it, it is showing error.

Comment: Name the ListBox in the xaml and then use it in the code behind.

Comment: Share some code, where you want to selected value

Comment: @bit but I want the id also in the back end from listbox selection. Thanks

Comment: @VirajShah Yes, that is what I suggested you. In your Xaml name it to listbox1, then use listbox1 directly in the code behind..

Comment: @bit thanks buddy, keep helping!!stay blessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you, let me know if  doesn't  work.

```
void client_live_permissionCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.live_permissionCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          //var selectedItem = listBox or listicker.SelectedItem as yourType
            LIST data = YourListBox.SelectedItem as LIST;
            long id = data.Id;
            string name = data.Name;
        }
```